# Undefined variable that has been defined

Tags: php, undefined

I am trying to create a simple contact form and for some reason when I load my index.php file I get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: emailError in C:\xampp\htdocs\Coming Soon
>   Landing page\index.php on line 105

Here is my code: (the important parts are the PHP tags at the top, and the php tags in the "signup" section ID)

```
<?php

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

      $from = $_POST['email'];
      $to = 'carsonclark2009@gmail.com';
      $subject = 'email sign up';
      $message = 'please sign me up to the mailing list';

      if (!$_POST['email']) {
        $emailError = "Please enter a valid email Address";
      }

  }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
      <title>Landing Page</title>

      <!-- Bootstrap -->
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- Custom CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <!-- Fonts -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Just+Another+Hand" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatica+SC" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

      <section id="logo">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-md-12">
                <img src="img/my-logo.png" class="img-fluid">
              </div>

            </div>
        </div>

      </section>


      <section id="intro">

        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <p>We're working hard, we'll be ready to launch in...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </section>

        <section id="counter">

        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="countDown"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </section>

     <section id="icons">

        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <ul class="list-inline">
                    <a href="#"><li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa twitter fa-twitter-square fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa facebook fa-facebook-square fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa google fa-google-plus-square fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa instagram fa-instagram fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </section>

      <section id="signup">

        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <form class="form-inline" role="form" method="post" action="#signup">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="email" placeholder="enter your email">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-signup btn-sm" name="submit" value="send">Find out more</button>
                </form>
              <?php echo $emailError; ?>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

      </section>
```

I defined the variable at the top of the page, and to my knowledge (which is lacking) it should be working but before I even click submit I get this error. I'm wondering what's wrong. Any input is greatly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Have you considered the fact that the if-statement has not been entered? What if you are using a GET request, not a POST request?

Comment: the method in the form element is "post" so that shouldn't be an issue. I'm not sure what you mean by "the if-statement has not been entered?".

Comment: define it as empty at start `$emailError = ''`

Comment: Well, You can do two things.

1. Use `@` before your variable like `<?php echo @$emailError; ?>`, that will ignore your warning at front-end, but this is very bad programming.

2. Check for the value is set or not using some `if..else` conditions.

Comment: The first request to the page, `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` will not be entered. Therefore, your variable is not defined

Comment: Define the variable at top in your PHP script then it will work.

Comment: Declaring it outside of the statement fixed it. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I defined the variable at the top of the page.

```
if (!$_POST['email']) {
    $emailError = "Please enter a valid email Address";
}
```

No, you're defining this variable in an if statement, maybe condition is false.

Declare variable at the top outside if statement or use this code:

```
<?php if (!empty($emailError)) { echo $emailError;} ?>
```

Note: consider replacing this code

```
if (!$_POST['email'])
```

with

```
if (!isset($_POST['email']))
```

Comment: This fixed it. Thank you so much. I still don't understand how my teacher got his code working without declaring it outside the statement but regardless.. thanks!

Comment: Maybe your teacher was calling this script with email post variable always valorized ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You must define $emailError variable at top

```
 $emailError = "";
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  $from = $_POST['email'];
  $to = 'carsonclark2009@gmail.com';
  $subject = 'email sign up';
  $message = 'please sign me up to the mailing list';

  if (!$_POST['email']) {
    $emailError = "Please enter a valid email Address";
  }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable will be defined only if **if-condition** will be true.

You can define default value to prevent errors;

```
<?php

  $emailError = '';

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

      $from = $_POST['email'];
      $to = 'carsonclark2009@gmail.com';
      $subject = 'email sign up';
      $message = 'please sign me up to the mailing list';

      if (!$_POST['email']) {
        $emailError = "Please enter a valid email Address";
      }

  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
 <?php echo $emailError; ?>
```

use this

```
 <?php if(isset($emailError)){ echo $emailError;} ?>
```

or just put `@` symbol before your `$emailError` variable to disable error reporting for that line

Comment: You can replace it with more short ternary operator:
 <?= isset($emailError)? $emailError : '' ?>

Comment: And please, do not advice developers to use @ to hide errors - it is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

First of all define `$emailError` as empty at top, this will not give you Undefined Variable notice, like:

```
<?php
$emailError = '';
// your code .....
```

And than you can further check if you need either `$emailError` set or not, like:

```
<?php 
if(!empty($emailError)){
  echo $emailError; 
}
?>
```